# Ambient operating temperature

Tags: pi-3b+

Will the raspberry pi be able to operate with an ambient temperature of between 50c to 80c?
The model we are using is the raspberry pi 3 b+.

Comment: air flow is way more important then what the actual ambient temperature is. Locked in a box at 20c might be worse then 50c with moving air, its all about how much heat can be dissipated. And these questions usually come down to the answer being "Try it and see" there are just too many factors like air movement, humidity, cpu/gpu load to determine what level of cooling(if any) will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't so much be the ambient temperature that would be the issue, but the CPU operating temperature.  At higher ambient temperatures and lower differential temperatures, it is more difficult to remove generated heat.  CPU load will also be a factor.  So the question is really "Can the CPU temperature be kept below the max rated 85℃?"

At 80℃ ambient temperature, it is unlikely you would be able to achieve this without some kind of active cooling in place.  In practice, I've seen about a 25℃ CPU operating temperature differential over ambient (in the 50℃-60℃ range) with just low to moderate CPU loads on a RasPi 3B+.

Answer (score 1):

Will **you** "be able to operate with an ambient temperature of between 50℃ to 80℃"?

The Pi itself will work, but without cooling will get warmer and begin to throttle back clock speed to keep its temperature in a safe range.
For the 3B+ the default soft limit is 60°C
See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-performance

You will see an Over temperature warning if the SoC temperature exceeds 80℃ See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/warning-icons.md